Mybatis kotlin dynamic sql update to newest 1.5.0 trouble with isIn
I'm converting a couple of pieces of code to the newest mybatis dynamic sql, and this line is giving me fits:
** Old Code - won't compile with newest version **
fencingSupportMapper.select { where<Int>(facility, isIn(*searchData.selectedFacilities!!)) }
** New Code (not working but compiles) **
val fencingForFacilities: List<Fencing> = fencingSupportMapper.select { where { facility isIn { searchData.selectedFacilities } }
My error is You must specify a select statement in a sub query
Now, my searchData.selectedFacilities is a list of Int values (and the facility column for the WHERE is an int.
Can someone see what's wrong? I've looked at the docs and don't see what's going on here...

Finally figured it out:
fencingSupportMapper.select { where { facility.isIn(*searchData.selectedFacilities!!) } }
